# Remove icon on last clicked span

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

## Problem

I'm trying to hide the Font Awesome "plus" icon on only the last clicked `span.highlight` and show it on spans without the class of `active`, but right now it's removing the icon on both of the spans and doesn't not show up after the active class has been added.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dg6w2sk2/

### scripts.js

```
$(".highlight").click(function() {
   $(".highlight").removeClass("active"); // Remove active class from spans
   $(this).addClass("active");  // Add an active class to span just clicked
   $(".fa-plus-circle").hide();  // Remove plus sign on active span
   $(".info").fadeIn(); // Fade in the info box to the left
});
```

### index.html

```
<p><span class="highlight underline active" title="Read about the 'Clutter Hoarding Scale'"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Next level church-key Shoreditch brunch</span> readymade. Chia pickled whatever, Blue Bottle farm-to-table messenger bag Neutra disrupt you probably haven't heard of them keytar dreamcatcher biodiesel banjo cardigan. Actually cliche you probably haven't heard of them put a bird on it tattooed, cray Bushwick irony selfies synth lomo gastropub. <span class="highlight underline"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Tousled occupy Schlitz Austin.</span></p>
```

Comment: I've altered your jsfiddle, just check out if it's working as you expect please and let me know: http://jsfiddle.net/dg6w2sk2/6/

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted it to do.

Comment: I've posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$(".highlight").click(function() {
       $(".highlight").removeClass("active"); // Remove active class from spans
        $(".fa-plus-circle").show();

       $(".info").fadeIn(); // Fade in the info box to the left

       var active = $(this).hasClass("active");
       /*if (active) {
            $(this).find(".fa-plus-circle").hide();  // Remove plus sign on active span
       } else {
            $(this).find(".fa-plus-circle").show();
       }*/

        $(this).addClass("active");  // Add an active class to span just
        $(this).find(".fa-plus-circle").hide();
    });
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dg6w2sk2/6/